# Train time series in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I wish to train a RNN model such that I can predict for T steps ahead in a time series model. Most of the examples that I have seen so far are centred around text.

The toy example that I have is to predict 3 sine waves as shown below:

```py
x = torch.arange(0,30,0.05)
y = [torch.sin(x), torch.sin(x-np.pi), torch.sin(x-np.pi/2)]
y = torch.stack(y)
y = y.t()
```

y is of shape `600,3`. However in order for the LSTM to accept it the input needs to be of shape `(seq_len, batch, input_size)`. I was wondering if there is a function in pytorch that converts them to required format. Suppose that in my case I want `seq_len=50` and `batch_size=32`.

This snippet of code from [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-with-deep-learning-in-python-with-keras/) was the only snippet of code I found.

```py
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
```

Does `pad_packed_sequence` or anything similar in pytorch natively do this.

If anyone is interested, this is my LSTM model:

```py
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, h, num_layers=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(n_features, h, num_layers)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(h, n_features)

    def forward(self, input, h=None):
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(input, h)
        return self.linear(lstm_out)
```

[optional Q] For whatever solution that I end up with, is there a way to ensure that I can do stateful training?